# Currency (FX) order with IBrokers in TWS

Tags: r, ibrokers

I am able to use IBrokers to submit standard futures and equity orders through the API.  When I try the same methodology for spot FX, I don't receive an error message, yet the order doesn't come through the TWS working window as it does with the other contract types.

```
contract = twsCurrency("EUR.USD")

Order = twsOrder(
  reqIds(tws),
  action = "BUY",
  totalQuantity = 1000000,
  orderType = "LMT",
  lmtPrice = 1.0600
)

placeOrder(tws, 
           Contract = contract, 
           Order)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the end was the numeric value `1000000` as it was cast to a character string.  In that process, the conversion was first to a scientific notation, which is not accepted by the TWS API.  To correct this, setting `options(scipen = 12)` or some very large value in the place of 12.